# How to fit div to image?

Tags: html, css

I have a fluid image inside a div, under the image there is an other div with text. Is it possible for the #text div to get same size like the image?

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/c7c1c7/fff.jpg">
    <div id="text">Several standard dimensions are included in dummyimage.com including ad sizes and screen resolution sizes.</div>
</div>


#container {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    max-width:100%; max-height:100%;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HUsRm/)

Comment: So what is ultimate aim - to center the text over the image or to have the div and the image same size? Also, would you be willing to use jquer/javascript?

Comment: I think you are likely to do like this>>> http://jsfiddle.net/HUsRm/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the answer on **JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HUsRm/8/) 
You need to add a `position:absolute` to your `<div id="text">..</div>`:

Here is the css you should apply:

```
#text{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;left:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#444;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:14px;
    padding:2px 0;
}
```

Comment: This is *on top* of the bottom part of the image, rather than *under the image* as specified in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Seeing as the `#container` is relatively positioned, you could position the `#text` absolutely, to prevent it from stretching the `#container`:

```
#text {
    /* remove from flow, prevents from stretching container */
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HUsRm/5/

This will, of course, **also prevent vertical stretching**, and not push following content down. This might be unwanted?

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work by having only this css:

```
#container
{
    display:table-caption;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUsRm/9/)

Comment: Actually, this looks horrible in IE10 :( I would still love an explanation of what makes this code "work" though

Answer (score 0):

try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HUsRm/3/)

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    max-width:100%; max-height:100%;
}
#text{
    max-width:300px;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but if i dont know the size of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your [**fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/HUsRm/7/). You just need to give position to text div.

```
#text {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Ya now you are just rep farming, aren't you? Read what [xec](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17484641/1542290) answered

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the proper tags: **figure** and **figcaption**, anyway here is a clean solution that also works with your markup, you can see the results in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XTCEn/).

```
    figure, #container {
            display: table;
            max-width: 100%; 
            width: auto !important;
            }

        img {
            display: table-row;
            max-width: 100%;
            width:100%;
        }

        figcaption, #text {
            display: table-caption;
            max-width: inherit;
            caption-side: bottom;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><style type="text/css">
    img,
    figcaption {
        width: auto !important;
    }
    </style><![endif]-->
    <figure>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/c7c1c7/fff.jpg" alt="alt text" />
        <figcaption>Several standard dimensions are included in dummyimage.com including ad sizes and screen resolution sizes.</figcaption>
    </figure>
<!-- YOUR MARKUP #2 -->
    <div id="container">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/c7c1c7/fff.jpg" alt="alt text" />
        <div id="text">Several standard dimensions are included in dummyimage.com including ad sizes and screen resolution sizes.</div>

    </div>
```

I would also suggest to take a look at [this blog post](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images/) for a better image resize